# Espresso test takes forever when ImageView is rotated

Tags: android, testing, android-testing, android-espresso

I have two similar `ImageView`s. I decided to not create different drawables for the second `ImageView` and rotate it using the same drawables.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/rightTurn_imageView"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/width_imageViews_feedback_area_info"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/height_imageViews_feedback_area_info"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_before_imageViews_feedback_area_info"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_before_imageViews_feedback_area_info"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_above_imageViews_feedback_area_info"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/emergency_imageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/feedback_area_info"
    android:rotation="180"/> <! -- The line where the problem occurs -->
```

I am trying to test my UI using `Espresso`. I am trying to see if a Toast appears and the `Test` function takes forever.

```
@Test
fun showToastOnClickRightDirectionLight() {
    onView(withId(R.id.rightTurn_imageView))
        .perform(click())
    onView(
        withText(
            containsString(
                activityRule.activity.resources.getString(
                    R.string.long_click_info
                )
            )
        )
    )
        .inRoot(RootMatchers.withDecorView(not(activityRule.activity.window.decorView)))
        .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
}
```

Whenever I remove the rotation line from xml (`android:rotation="180"`) the test completes successfully. 

*When I am testing the UI, with my finger(!) everything it works as it should, even if it is rotated or not.*

Is there any workaround for this problem, or should I create another drawable?

Also, can somebody explain why is this happening? What is wrong when `rotating`?

Answer (score 0):

look at link below section `2.3 -> Device settings`:

> It is recommended to turn of the animation on the Android device which
>   is used for testing. Animations might confusing Espressos check for
>   ideling resources.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTestingEspresso/article.html

Comment: I have disabled the animations from settings. This `AnimationDrawable` should be shown. The one of the 2 `ImageView`s is working as it should. If the `AnimationDrawable` was the problem, then the problem would be reproduced for both `ImageView`s.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `setRotation` may have affected coordinates calculation of the view on the screen. So you could try with a custom click action instead:

```
public static ViewAction forceClick() {
    return new ViewAction() {
        @Override public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
            return allOf(isClickable(), isEnabled(), isDisplayed());
        }

        @Override public String getDescription() {
            return "force click";
        }

        @Override public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
            view.performClick();
            uiController.loopMainThreadUntilIdle();
        }
    };
}
```

Then use it on a button or any view with click listener:

```
onView(withId(R.id.move_up)).perform(forceClick());
```